# How to prove compactness is a topological property by definition?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I learned from the lectures that a property of a set which remains invariant under a homeomorphism is called topological property. And $S$ is compact in $X$ if every open cover of $S$ has a finite sub cover. But I do not know how to connect these two definitions to prove that compactness is a topological property.

Comment: What's a "topological mapping"?

Comment: Can your prove that a space which is homeomorphic to a compact space is also compact?

Comment: A topological mapping is the same as homeomorphism I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wry term topological mapping most likely means a homeomorphism,
a continuous bijection with a continuous inverse.
Topological properties are about spaces.
They are not about subsets.

Let $X$ be a compact space and $h:X\to Y$ a homeomorphism.
Let $C$ be an open cover of $Y$.
Show $\{ h^{-1}(A) : A \in C\}$ is an open cover of $X$.
Is this a sufficient start of a proof to encourage you to finish it?

Comment: You are an experimented user, so why don't you use [MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried this. 
We wish to show that Y is a compact space, i.e. every open cover of Y has a finite sub cover. 
Let C be an open cover of Y, since X is compact,  {h-1(A): A in C  is an open cover of X} has finite sub cover, say {h-1(A1),h-1(A2),...,h-1(An)}.
Since h is bijective and continuous, then {A1, A2, ..., An} is a finite sub cover of Y. 
Hence, Y is compact, and compactness is a topological property. 
Is there any problem about this proof?

Comment: The notation is terrible and the first pair of set brackets a disaster. @Jason